# Broken Json File

Tags: json

I am asking here today to help with a JSON file. I am a Vtuber, so I have a virtual avatar that can move around and all that. One of my files for another version of the said avatar has a JSON file that seems to be broken.

I bought the rigging since I have absolutely no idea how to code, this was made for me. That being said, I cannot find a solution for this anywhere, nor can I understand it. I've tried putting into to compilers and validators, but I do not understand what is being said. Any precise help is truly appreciated, literally telling me where a comma or anything goes lol. I have contacted the rig maker, but they don't understand the issue. Here is the code as follows, and what the validators tell me is the issue :

```
{
"Version": 1,
"Name": "ponky",
"FileReferences": {
    "Icon": "icon.png",
    "Model": "ponky.model3.json",
    "IdleAnimation": ""
},
"ModelPositionMovement": {
    "Use": true,
    "X": 6,
    "Y": 8,
    "Z": 11,
    "SmoothingX": 10,
    "SmoothingY": 10,
    "SmoothingZ": 10
},
"PhysicsSettings": {
    "Use": true,
    "PhysicsStrength": 50,
    "WindStrength": 0
},
"ParameterSettings": [{
        "Name": "Face Left/Right Rotation",
        "Input": "FaceAngleX",
        "InputRangeLower": -30.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 30.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": -30.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 30.0,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamAngleX",
        "Smoothing": 15
    },
    {
        "Name": "Face Up/Down Rotation",
        "Input": "FaceAngleY",
        "InputRangeLower": -20.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 20.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": -30.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 30.0,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamAngleY",
        "Smoothing": 15
    },
    {
        "Name": "Face Lean Rotation",
        "Input": "FaceAngleZ",
        "InputRangeLower": -30.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 30.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": -30.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 30.0,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamAngleZ",
        "Smoothing": 30
    },
    {
        "Name": "Eye Open Left",
        "Input": "Brows",
        "InputRangeLower": 0.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 1.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": 0.4000000059604645,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 1.2000000476837159,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": true,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamEyeLOpen",
        "Smoothing": 15
    },
    {
        "Name": "Eye Open Right",
        "Input": "Brows",
        "InputRangeLower": 0.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 1.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": 0.4000000059604645,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 1.2000000476837159,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": true,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamEyeROpen",
        "Smoothing": 15
    },
    {
        "Name": "Eye X",
        "Input": "FaceAngleX",
        "InputRangeLower": -30.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 30.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": 1.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": -1.0,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamEyeBallX",
        "Smoothing": 15
    },
    {
        "Name": "Eye Y",
        "Input": "FaceAngleY",
        "InputRangeLower": -30.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 30.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": 0.30000001192092898,
        "OutputRangeUpper": -0.8999999761581421,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamEyeBallY",
        "Smoothing": 15
    },
    {
        "Name": "Brow Form Left",
        "Input": "Brows",
        "InputRangeLower": 0.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 1.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": -1.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 1.0,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamBrowLForm",
        "Smoothing": 15
    },
    {
        "Name": "Brow Form Right",
        "Input": "Brows",
        "InputRangeLower": 0.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 1.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": -1.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 1.0,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamBrowRForm",
        "Smoothing": 15
    },
    {
        "Name": "Mouth Smile",
        "Input": "MouthSmile",
        "InputRangeLower": 0.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 1.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": -1.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 1.0,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamMouthForm",
        "Smoothing": 7
    },
    {
        "Name": "Mouth Open",
        "Input": "MouthOpen",
        "InputRangeLower": 0.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 1.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": 0.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 1.5,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamMouthOpenY",
        "Smoothing": 5
    },
    {
        "Name": "Body Rotation X",
        "Input": "FaceAngleX",
        "InputRangeLower": -30.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 30.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": -10.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 10.0,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamBodyAngleX",
        "Smoothing": 20
    },
    {
        "Name": "Body Rotation Y",
        "Input": "FaceAngleY",
        "InputRangeLower": -30.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 30.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": -10.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 10.0,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamBodyAngleY",
        "Smoothing": 20
    },
    {
        "Name": "Body Rotation Z",
        "Input": "FaceAngleZ",
        "InputRangeLower": -30.0,
        "InputRangeUpper": 30.0,
        "OutputRangeLower": -10.0,
        "OutputRangeUpper": 10.0,
        "ClampInput": false,
        "ClampOutput": false,
        "UseBlinking": false,
        "UseBreathing": false,
        "OutputLive2D": "ParamBodyAngleZ",
        "Smoothing": 20
    }
],
"Hotkeys": [{
            "Name": "",
            "Action": "ToggleExpression",
            "File": "Angry.exp3.json",
            "Position": {
                "X": 0.0,
                "Y": 0.0,
                "Z": 0.0,
                "Rotation": 0.0
            },
            "Triggers": {
                "Trigger1": "LeftControl",
                "Trigger2": "A",
                "ScreenButton": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "",
            "Action": "ToggleExpression",
            "File": "Happy.exp3.json",
            "Position": {
                "X": 0.0,
                "Y": 0.0,
                "Z": 0.0,
                "Rotation": 0.0
            },
            "Triggers": {
                "Trigger1": "",
                "Trigger2": "",
                "ScreenButton": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "",
            "Action": "ToggleExpression",
            "File": "Neutral.exp3.json",
            "Position": {
                "X": 0.0,
                "Y": 0.0,
                "Z": 0.0,
                "Rotation": 0.0
            },
            "Triggers": {
                "Trigger1": "",
                "Trigger2": "",
                "ScreenButton": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "",
            "Action": "ToggleExpression",
            "File": "Sad.exp3.json",
            "Position": {
                "X": 0.0,
                "Y": 0.0,
                "Z": 0.0,
                "Rotation": 0.0
            },
            "Triggers": {
                "Trigger1": "",
                "Trigger2": "",
                "ScreenButton": 4
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "",
            "Action": "TriggerAnimation",
            "File": "Smile.motion3.json",
            "Position": {
                "X": 0.0,
```

### Error: Parse error on line 289:
...n": {                    "X": 0.0,

Expecting 'STRING', got 'EOF'

Comment: "EOF" means "End of file". And that error "Expecting 'STRING', got 'EOF" means, the JSON is cut off at exactly there and it is not complete anymore.

Comment: The parser reports that it got EOF rather than a String - EOF is end-of-file.You can see how it abruptly ends `{ "X": 0.0,`.  With formatting, I'm sure you can see how curly-braces and square braces are are supposed to align.  It looks like your JSON has been cut off.

Comment: Ah...so the file isn't even completed? Well that answers that I suppose.